# VBA code to copy a Teradata query result into Pdf file

Tags: vba, excel, teradata

I am having a doubt in Excel VBA. Is it possible to get the result of a query executed in Teradata exported into Pdf file? Can please someone share the VBA code for this?

I am having all the connections and other stuffs done. I am only stuck when exporting the result into a Pdf file from the Teradata result window

Thanks,
Philip

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with Teradata. This code works with Excel data linked via the MsQuery ODBC to the TD backend:

```
Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

set xlWB = xlObj.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sys\1.xls")

xlWB.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat 0, "C:\Sys\1" & ".pdf", 0, 1, 0, , ,0

xlWB.close False

xlObj.quit
```